# How to simulate stock exchange data (OHLC chart) realistically?

Tags: metadata

The stock market is described in many places (e.g. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_walk_hypothesis)) as a random walk. Among the various arguments against this hypothesis, nowhere is mentioned what struck me to be the most obvious one: every stock has a lower bound of 0. A random walk, however, is unbound.

I can think of various ways to implement such a bound in a simulation that generates artificial stock market data. **But are there ways to simulate a stock market where a lower bound of 0 follows from economical considerations (i.e., a market theory) instead of practical improvisation.**